# Want to start a new Castleville account on my iPad

Tags: ipad, games

I downloaded my friends Castleville account on my iPad. Now I would like to start my own Castleville game. I uninstalled her game and removed all the data from Game Center. Next I went to the App Store to install the game but it has the little cloud icon with the down arrow on it. When I install it the game is still hers. Is there a way to download a game as if it's never been used before on my device so that I can play my own game from the beginning? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is likely because her Apple ID is being used for Game Center.  To fix will require that you have your own Apple ID.

- Go to **Settings**
- Tap **Game Center**
- If you see her Apple ID, change it to yours

If that doesn't work, This is because the game either stores game data in iCloud or somewhere other than just in Game Center.  To fix will require that you check with the developer on which Apple ID affects game status.

If signing out of Game Center doesn't fix things, then delete the app and all of its data. Then re-download the app. Lastly, before launching, use your Game Center account/Apple ID.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I've done all of your suggestions. It is my Apple ID in Game Center. In fact, I have two Game Center ID's and the game loads her progress on both accounts. Not sure if this is a developer issue, Game Center issue, or Apple iCloud issue. Frustrating